# Cannot reference a class in portable project from UWP project

Tags: c#, class, xamarin, uwp

I am trying to reference a public class in my portable project from the UWP project but it does not allow me to.

Here is my project file structure:

[[image: 1]]

Here is the class located in the portable project:
[image]

Here is the class located in the UWP project, you'll notice it cannot access the class from the portable project:
[image]

And here's what happens when I use the dot operator, the UWP namespace is the only thing that appears.

[image]

Any ideas on why I cannot access the public class in the portable project? Or how I can access that class?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your portable class library targeting?

Comment: @KenTucker What do you mean by targeting?

Comment: @KenTucker You mean these?

https://ibb.co/gELr2a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Ken Tucker your question shed light on the issue.

Windows 10 was not selected in the targets.

I did the following:

- Uninstall Xamarin.Forms from the portable project using NuGet
- Check the Windows 10 box in the targets of the portable project
- Reinstall Xamarin.Forms to the portable project

Glad it was an easy solution!

Comment: Just did, I've never thought about accepting my own reply as an answer because usually it's other people who have the answers!